# Did al-Qadi an-Nu'man write a book entitled "Al-Fiqh al-Akbar"?

Tags: shiism, islamic-scholar, books, aqidah

[Al-Qadi an-Nu'man](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Al-Qadi_al-Nu%27man&oldid=1175249582) القاضي النعمان or Abu Hanifa al-Nu‘man ibn Muhammad ibn Mansur ibn Ahmad ibn Hayyun al-Tamimi (died 974 CE/ 363 AH) the Isma'ili jurist and official historian of the [Fatimid](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fatimid_Caliphate&oldid=1187947151) dynasty. Had certainly written a lot of books and papers to defend the Fatmid dynasty and the Isma'ili and in general Shi'a jurisprudence and belief.

Arabic Wikipedia says he first was a follower of the Maliki school of fiqh. His name certainly may create confusion with that of abu Hanifa the known Sunni scholar and "founder" of the hanafi maddhab.

I wonder if he compiled a book entitled (or maybe referred to as) "Al-Fiqh al-Akbar" - a book with the same title is known to have been compiled by abu Hanifa-, if so what is the topic of this book?

Also what books did he write about Creed and Aqeedah?

Comment: A book called al-Fiqh al-Akbar is also attributed to Abu Hanifa (the Sunni Imam).

Comment: @Uma I know but there's a certain doubt about it being correctly attributed to him. Due to some statements. In fact the Fatimid called ibn Hayyun abu Hanifa to create more confusion!

Answer (score -1):

Has Al-Qazi Nu'man written a book entitled "Al-Fiqh Al-Akbar"?
Sharh Kitab al-Fiqh al-Akbar written by Abu Hanifa al-Nu'man ibn Thabit al-Kufi and narrated in Arabic by Imam Mullah Ali al-Qari.

Ref;https://wikinoor.ir/%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%AD_%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%83%D8%A8%D8%B1